# Sticky Navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a 'fixed' class to a menu once the scroller hits that menu. I've managed to get it working, but having problems removing the class once the user scrolls back to the top.

Here is the site I'm working on: http://www.allbyor.com/

Here's is my JS code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var menu = $('.bottom-row');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= menu.offset().top) {
        menu.addClass('menufix');
    } else {
        menu.removeClass('menufix');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the original value of the menu.`offset().top` in a variable, because once you change its class to **fixed** the **top value** will be the same as the `$(window).scrollTop()`.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/96j6e7f8/).

```
var menu = $('.bottom-row');
var menu_top_value = menu.offset().top;

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= menu_top_value) {
        menu.addClass('menufix');

    } else {
        menu.removeClass('menufix');
    }
});
```